# Vertex normals look different in PyVista and Blender

Tags: python, blender, mesh, normals, pyvista

I'm working with a mesh of a cave, and have manually set all the face normals to be 'correct' (all faces facing outside) using Blender (Edit mode-> choose faces -> flip normal). I also visualised the vertex normals in Blender, and they are all pointed outwards all through the surface:

[image: Blender normals of cave scan]

The mesh is then exported as an STL file.

Now, however, when I visualise the same thing in Pyvista with the following code:

```
import pyvista as pv
cave = pv.read("data/OC_wellsliced.stl")
cave.plot_normals()
```

The normals point in very different (below), and sometimes opposite directions. Any help in understanding this discrepancy would be greatly appreciated!

[image: screenshot from pyvista showing normal vector plot with a bunch of them pointing inward]

The `OC_wellsliced.stl` STL file is [here](https://github.com/thejasvibr/sound_prop_in_cave/tree/master/data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The convenience functions for your case seem a bit *too* convenient.

What `plot_normals()` does under the hood is that it accesses `cave.point_normals`, which in turn calls `cave.compute_normals()`. [The default arguments to `compute_normals()`](https://dev.pyvista.org/api/core/_autosummary/pyvista.PolyData.compute_normals.html) include `consistent_normals=True`, which according to the docs does

> Enforcement of consistent polygon ordering.

There are some other parameters which hint at potential black magic going on when running this filter (e.g. `auto_orient_normals` and `non_manifold_ordering`, even though the defaults seem safe).

So what seems to happen is that your mesh (which is non manifold, i.e. it has open edges) breaks the magic that `compute_normals` tries to do with the default "enforcement of polygon ordering". Since you already enforced the correct order in Blender, you can tell pyvista (well, VTK) to leave your polygons alone and just compute the normals as they are. This is not possible through `plot_normals()`, so you need a bit more work:

```py
import pyvista as pv

# read data
cave = pv.read("OC_wellsliced.stl")

# compute normals
# cave = cave.compute_normals()  # default (wrong) behaviour
cave = cave.compute_normals(consistent_normals=False)  # correct behaviour

# plot the normals manually; plot_normals() won't work
plotter = pv.Plotter()
plotter.add_mesh(cave, color='silver')
plotter.add_mesh(cave.glyph(geom=pv.Arrow(), orient='Normals'), color='black')
plotter.view_vector([-1, -1, 1])
plotter.show()
```

[image: screenshot of fixed normals, all pointing outward]

You can uncomment the default call to `compute_normals()` to reproduce the original behaviour of `plot_normals()`. More importantly, you now have point and cell arrays called `'Normals'` on your mesh that you can use for any kind of postprocessing. And these are guaranteed to be sane, because they are exactly what we plotted in the above figure.

---

I now notice that you also said "in very different [...] directions"; I was focussing on the sign flips. Unfortunately it's very hard to see the normals in your Blender screenshot, so I can't tackle that. It's possible that point normals (as opposed to face normals) are computed differently between the two. Cell normals should be well-defined for flat polygonal cells.

Comment: The sign flips is the main concern and it seems like some of the directions are a bit different - but this is more of a qualitative observation. Learnt a bunch of new things here. Was unable to view the mesh + normals in a Plotter scene because I didn't realise I could access attributes (like normals) as another mesh layer - this answer clarified things a lot!

Comment: @Thejasvi in fact the mesh read from input doesn't explicitly contain normals, and the original call to `plot_normals()` doesn't store them. You've probably figured out by now, but just to be on the safe side: you now have `cave.point_data['Normals']` and the same for `cell_data` which are arrays of the corresponding data with shape `(cave.n_points, 3)` and `(cave.n_cells, 3)`, respectively. Glad I could help :)